Long curly braces in quiver diagram
I made this diagram using https://q.uiver.app/

This is the corresponding Latex code:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{quiver}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzcd}
    C && c \\
    \\
    B && b \\
    \\
    A && a
    \arrow[from=3-1, to=1-1]
    \arrow[from=3-3, to=1-3]
    \arrow[from=5-1, to=3-1]
    \arrow[from=5-3, to=3-3]
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}

Please note that you need to have an additional file quiver.sty in your directory to do \usepackage{quiver} which can be found here: link
But I want to add a long curly brace from A to B on the left of the diagram. How can I do it?

You don't need quiver.sty for such diagram: \usepackage{tikz-cd} is enough.

@egreg this was just an example, the diagram I need is much bigger

Using tikz-cd:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{quiver}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{tikzcd}
    C && c \\
    \\
    B && b \\
    \\
    A && a
    \arrow[from=3-1, to=1-1]
    \arrow[from=3-3, to=1-3]
    \arrow[from=5-1, to=3-1]
    \arrow[from=5-3, to=3-3]
    \arrow[from=5-1, to=3-1, xshift=-0.3cm, decorate, no head, decoration={brace}]
  \end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}


If you need more control over the size and position, you could use tikz:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{quiver}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{tikzcd}[execute at end picture={
    \draw[decorate,decoration = {brace},transform canvas={xshift=-0.3cm}] (\tikzcdmatrixname-5-1.center) -- (\tikzcdmatrixname-3-1.center);
  }]
    C && c \\
    \\
    B && b \\
    \\
    A && a
    \arrow[from=3-1, to=1-1]
    \arrow[from=3-3, to=1-3]
    \arrow[from=5-1, to=3-1]
    \arrow[from=5-3, to=3-3]
  \end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}



A few suggestions.

Use tikz-cd with 3 rows and 2 columns. You can adjust the spacing with row sep and column sep instead of creating empty rows and columns.
The brace can be created as an arrow using decorate, decoration=brace (which requires the decorations.pathreplacing library). Specify start anchor and end anchor  to enclose the cells.


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1.5cm, column sep=1.8cm]
    C & c \\
    B\arrow[u, "g"description] & b\arrow[u, mapsto] \\
    A\arrow[u, "f"description]\arrow[u, -, start anchor=south west, end anchor=north west, decorate, decoration={brace}] & a\arrow[u, mapsto]
  \end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}

